# Proof : $ \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}(0 \leq a<\epsilon) \to a =0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. I must prove:

$ \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}(0 \leq a<\epsilon) \to a =0$

Proof: If  $a<\epsilon$ then $a< \epsilon +0$, by [the property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622403/proof-by-contradiction-forall-epsilon-in-mathbbr0a-be-to-a-le) I have $a \leq 0$ and by hypothesis $a \geq 0$. Therefore $a=0$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Hint: If $a>0$ then $a\in \mathbb R^{>0}$.

Comment: Using the theorem from your earlier post, this seems right to me.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks for hint! ;) :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's correct.

There's an alternative answer: we have
$$\forall \epsilon >0\quad 0\le a<\epsilon$$
so the set $\mathbb R_{>0}$ is bounded below by $a$ but $0$ is the infimum of $\mathbb R_{>0}$ so $a\le 0$ and since $a\ge0$ then $a=0$.

Comment: thanks for alternative answer! :) ;)

Comment: Thanks for saying those kind words. :)

Answer (score 5):

If $a>0$, then we have $0\le a<a$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, most answers seem to neglect showing that $a\ge 0$ in the first place.
Assume $\forall \epsilon \in\mathbb R^{>0}(0\le a<\epsilon)$. Especially for $\epsilon = 1\in\mathbb R^{>0}$ this shows $0\le a<1$, hence $a=0$ or $a>0$. The latter case leads to the contradiction $0\le a<a$. Hence $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using sequences : We have :
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, 0 \leq a < \dfrac{1}{n} \to 0$$
Then $a = 0$.